# notify iOS & Android on data change on server

Tags: android, ios, server

I'm creating mobile application for iOS and Android. The problem is when any data has changed on server, I cannot notify mobile devices.

I have found 3 solutions, each have minus and pluses.

1. Use push notifications. Since iOS always shows a notification to user this is not a solution at all. Also I cannot know if the notification will go to device or when it will.
2. For every X seconds ask server if any change exists. I don't want to do that, because creating too many HTTP connections and closing them is not a good idea I think. Also if the data is changed right after the device asks, the info change on device will occur late.
3. Use web socket. My application's one time usage expectation is ~2 minutes. So web socket looks like a good choice, because app will be terminated or go to background state quickly and battery consume won't be much. Also all the server side data changes will come to the device just in time. But I don't know much about web socket. Is my opinion acceptable? Also how many concurrent connections can be done by my server. Is it a question too.

Here are my all solutions.

Comment: What kind of application is this required..I would suggest websockets as I've found it to be useful for server to client communication..

Comment: app have objects stated open-willCloseInTenMinutes-closed. I have to notify user when that object state changed -almost exact time-. None of the users should see the closed object as open or willClose

Comment: I would recommend using web sockets since it appears like your server needs to communicate with the client very frequently and instantly.

Comment: Very frequent is not in my situation, but instant is.

Answer (score 2):

The document would suggest assumption 1. above is incorrect.

If you read the **The Notification Payload** section, you'll come across this;

The aps dictionary can also contain the content-available property. The content-available property with a value of 1 lets the remote notification act as a “silent” notification. When a silent notification arrives, iOS wakes up your app in the background so that you can get new data from your server or do background information processing. Users aren’t told about the new or changed information that results from a silent notification, but they can find out about it the next time they open your app.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html

Comment: Ok. I have a mistake at there. Thank you for the information, but notification state (transmission state) is still unknown. Any device may not receive the notification

Comment: APNS is very accurate. Notifications received by the device just in time -generally-  But GCM is not. Sometimes an Android device receiving nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I think for the most part this depends on what your app is doing.

I would say you should use a combination of #1 and #2.

2 - At the very base level if you need information from the server you are going to have to make a request. If this information needs to be up to date then you can proceed to make a request for the information when the ViewController is loaded. If you need this information to update as the ViewController is loaded then you will need to make subsequent requests every X seconds... In addition to this if your user is interacting with this data and sending an update to the server you can check at this point if the data is up to date and alert the user as well as return the current data.

1 - Push Notifications operate off of the 'send and forget' protocol. The notification is sent and is not verified if it is received or not. This is used as a supplement to #2 and is 'nice' but should not be depended upon.

Comment: It's not about updating data only. if it was, no problem, I could use #2. One of my old app running like this. But this time, app have objects stated open-willCloseInTenMinutes-closed. I have to notify user when that object state changed -almost exact time-. None of the users should see the  closed object as open or willClose

Comment: You will have a timer that will decrement to show time changing in real time. When this timer reaches X seconds it will hit the server and update the time. As the timer continues to count down if it reaches 10 minutes then it will hit the server and update the time and if it is indeed 10 minutes till close then you can update the user exactly at that time... same thing with closing time.

Answer (score 0):

Push notification is the intended way (from both Google through Google Cloud Messaging, and Apple through Apple Push Notification Service).

Both option 2 and 3 are frowned upon as they affect battery life, and they are unnecessary as most cases scenarios can be covered by push notifications.

Comment: As I mentioned, my app's expected ACTIVE TIME is too short, I'm not concerning about battery life. But I have no idea about OTHER SCENARIOS of web socket.